# How to change the display name of an iOS app in Xcode 10.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've tried with the "Bundle display name" key in info.plist and changed the value to the new name, but when I install the app on my phone, it still appears with the old name.

Answer (score 5):

Please check if you are using localization for `Info.plist`

In the `InfoPlist.strings` you can localize the different keys from your Info.plist. Find for something like below:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Your app name";
"CFBundleName"  = "Your app name";
```

Comment: I changed that too, this is from my info.plist: `<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>` `<string>New name</string>` `<key>CFBundleName</key>` `<string>New name</string>`

Answer (score 0):

please try installing your app on a new phone or reset the current phone and it should start displaying the new app name.
You could also verify this on a simulator.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of the info.plist?